# Raster Merge from each folder using Mosaic To new raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, modelbuilder, merge

[image]

I have rasters in each folder and I want to merge rasters of each folder and save them individually. In above model I am able to merge all rasters from both folders. Any way I can fix this in a model builder?

Raster of C1- Will be saved as C1_Merged
Raster of C2- Will be saved as C2_Merged

For showing purpose I have made 2 folders, I need to run on 1000 folders.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the help file on the subject of [embedding models within models](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-model-within-a-model.htm). You would have a master model that is iterating over folders (your C1 and C2) and that feeds each folder into a sub-model which would be the model in your sample image. You would pass the folder name into your sub-model using [inline variable substitution](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-inline-variable-substitution.htm).